# Converting timestamp from one column of an SQL table to dates in another column of the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, unix-timestamp

I'd like to convert unix timestamps from one column of an existing sql table to dates in another column of the same table. Something like this: take the values of column TIMESTAMP from every raw and convert it into a date and put it into column DATE.

I already figure out that the below expression converts the timestamps into dates:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(TIMESTAMP) FROM MYTABLE
```

but I don't know how to plug this into a normal sql update expression.

Thanks for any advice!
W

Comment: what type is `TIMESTAMP`?  what timezone does its data reflect, and is that the same as the timezone you want to use to determine the date?  Showing your schema, some sample data and expected results for that sample data is always helpful

Comment: from_unixtime does not convert into a date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the expression in the `SET` clause of the `UPDATE` query.

```
UPDATE MYTABLE 
SET date = FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)
```